# What is wrong with this stochastic calculus derivation?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Given stochastic processes $X_t, Y_t$ of form given below, we want to find $d(X_t Y_t)$.
Assume $$X_t=\sigma_tW_t + \mu_t t$$
$$Y_t=\rho_tW_t + \nu_t t$$

**I have two different answers depending on how I derive them, and *both of them are wrong*, but I don't know why**.

**Method 1:**

$X_tY_t=\sigma_t\rho_tW_t^2+(\sigma_t\nu_t+\mu_t\rho_t)tW_t+\mu_t\nu_tt^2$

Therefore $X_tY_t=f(W_t,t).$ Using Taylor expansion: $df(W_t,t)=\frac{\delta f}{\delta W_t}dW_t+(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta W_t^2}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta t})dt.$

Therefore:
$d(X_tY_t)=(2\sigma_t\rho_tW_t+\sigma_t\nu_t+\mu_t\rho_t)dW_t+2(\sigma_t\rho_t+\mu_t\nu_tt)dt$

**Method 2:**

However, if we use a different approach, by defining instead $g(X_t,Y_t)=X_tY_t$, then a Taylor polynomial gives: $$d(X_t,Y_t)=\frac{\delta g}{\delta X_t}dX_t+\frac{\delta ^2g}{\delta X_t^2}(dX_t)^2+\frac{\delta g}{\delta Y_t}dY_t+\frac{\delta^2 g}{\delta Y_t^2}(dY_t)^2+\frac{\delta^2 g}{\delta X_t\delta Y_t}dX_tdY_t$$
This results in:
$$d(X_tY_t)=Y_tdX_t+X_tdY_t+2dX_tdY_t$$
If I were to expand this, it would be quite big and definitely not equal to the result from (1).

**Both of these are wrong,** because my textbook gives an even different result, namely
$$d(X_tY_t)=Y_tdX_t+X_tdY_t+ \sigma_t\rho_tdt$$
I don't know how exactly they got there other than that they used $X_tY_t=\frac{1}{2}((X_t+Y_t)^2 - X_t^2 - Y_t^2)$.

---

I must be fundamentally misunderstanding something about stochastic calculus (I've only just started with it).

**What am I doing wrong, and what misunderstanding do I have?**

Comment: In your method 2, you missed a factor of $\dfrac{1}{2}$ for the $(dX_t)^2$ and $(dY_t)^2$ term.

Comment: Are you sure that $X_t=\sigma_tW_t+\mu_t t$ is correct? The equation $dX_t=\sigma_t dW_t+\mu_t dt$ seems more reasonable.

Comment: @ChrisVarghese, pff.. ok that explains it.

Comment: @Handschuh, Isn't the second equation derivable from the first? It is according to my textbook, if I'm not misinterpreting it.

Comment: The equation $dX_t=\sigma_t dW_t+\mu_t dt$ is shorthand for an integral equation $X_t-X_0=\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s+\int_0^t \mu_s ds$ (this is written "everywhere", e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Use_in_probability_and_mathematical_finance). So, for example $dX_t=W_tdW_t$ means $X_t=X_0+\frac{1}{2}W_t^2-\frac{t}{2}$.

Comment: Why is the $-\frac{t}{2}$ there? $\mu_s$ is zero, so you're getting it from the ito integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin from the end. You have the stochastic product rule
$$
d(X_t Y_t) = X_t dY_t + Y_t dX_y + dX_t dY_t,
$$
which is identical to your text book result if you note that $dX_t = \sigma_t$ and $dY_t = \rho_t$.

As for your method 1, you took the derivative wrong... To illustrate,
$$
d\left(\sigma_t \rho_t W_t^2 \right)
 = 2 \sigma_t \rho_t W_t dW_t + \sigma_t \rho_t dt
$$
while
$$
d\left[\left(\sigma_t \nu_t + \mu_t \rho_t\right)tW_t\right]
 = \left(\sigma_t \nu_t + \mu_t \rho_t\right)tdW_t 
 + W_t \frac{d\left[(\sigma_t \nu_t + \mu_t \rho_t)t\right]}{dt}dt
$$